# Enforce a constraint problem

Tags: database-design, oracle-11g-r2, constraint

This business model is for a case management database. This is closely modeled on the idea of a file folder representing the phase and a sequential checklist representing the stages. A case consists of a phase that can have one or more stages.  A phase can only have one stage that is "Current" or open at any one point in time.  A case can only start from one type of stage but can progress to any one of a number of stages that are end types. In this business model there are many different types of phases and stages

An example: you apply for a license. The process always starts with you submitting a form but can have different endings: the application is approved or rejected or sent back for more information.

Edit: @Colin 't Hart  asks what a phase is in relation to a case. Here is where trying to simplify a question can omit details.  The complete schema structure is:
- one case can have one or more phases but only one phase is open or "current" at at time. 
- each phase can have one or more stages but only one phase is open or "current" at a time.
- there are different types of cases/phases/stages and transitions from the current unit to the next unit require adding a close date to the current and inserting a new record with an open date.
An example: a production line for widgets

- a production ticket initiates the creation of the case
- the first phase: sourcing components is created
- the first stage: contacting suppliers is created
- the first stage is completed, the second stage: orders from suppliers is opened
- orders stage is closed, inventory check stage is created
- inventory stage is closed, sourcing components phase is closed
- new phase: assembly is opened
- new stage: move components to shop floor is opened
- moving components stage is closed, new stage production line is opened
- and so on....

Problem:

- the existing table structure is flawed in that the same information (what is the first type of stage for a kind of phase) is stored in two different tables
- You can have more than one entry in STAGE where IS_START_STAGE = 1 which violates a business rule
- You can insert a new entry into STAGE where IS_START_STAGE = 1 and this does not match the corresponding entry in PHASE_FIRST_STAGE
- the relationship should be something like constraint PHASE_FIRST_STAGE.STAGE_ID can only be in the entries in STAGE where IS_FIRST_STAGE = 1
- Is there anyway to enforce these business rules?

---

```
CREATE TABLE PHASE_FIRST_STAGE
(
  PHASE_ID           NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL, --PRIMARY KEY and foreign key to PHASE
  STAGE_ID           NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL,  --FOREIGN KEY to STAGE table
);
ALTER TABLE PHASE_FIRST_STAGE ADD (CONSTRAINT PFS01
  FOREIGN KEY (PHASE_ID) 
  REFERENCES PHASE (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (STAGE_ID) 
  REFERENCES STAGE (ID));
COMMENT ON TABLE PHASE_FIRST_STAGE IS 'Contains the default first stages to enter when a phase is entered.';

CREATE TABLE STAGE
(
  ID               NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL, --PRIMARY KEY
  PHASE_ID         NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL,  --FOREIGN KEY to PHASE
  DISABLED         NUMBER(1)           DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL,  --CHECK IN (0,1)
  IS_START_STAGE            NUMBER(1),--CHECK IN (0,1)
  IS_END_STAGE              NUMBER(1) --CHECK IN (0,1)
);

COMMENT ON TABLE STAGE IS 'Contains all the stages a phase can have. Each stage must have only one phase. ';
--not shown is a similar table called PHASE with a one phase => many type of stage relationship
```

Comment: If you have to add business logic in constraints, you can use triggers to enforce the business rules

Comment: I find it very difficult to understand what you're describing and how the datamodel is supposed to solve the problem. Could you separate the two: first describe purely your business -- without refering to the data model, and then describe how your data model implements it?

Comment: Can you give us examples of phases? I can understand how a case (for example, a driver's license application) could go through various stages (application, rejection, approval) but how do the phases come into it?

Answer (score 1):

Justin Cave's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317774/conditional-unique-constraint-in-oracle-db) and [Tom Kyte's](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1249800833250) pointed me to a solution using a function based index. I think this can be made even simpler with some more thought but this works now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNIQUE_START_STAGE (
   phase_id_in   IN NUMBER,
   stage_id_in   IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
   DETERMINISTIC
IS
 -- PURPOSE:enforce business logic that a phase can have only one stage where
 -- the disabled field has a value of 0 and IS_START_STAGE has a value of 1

   v_count   NUMBER (9);
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (s.id)
     INTO v_count
     FROM STAGE s
    WHERE     S.IS_START_STAGE = 1
          AND s.disabled = 0
          AND S.PHASE_ID = phase_id_in;

 IF v_count = 1
 THEN
     --return the primary key if there is only one
     v_count := stage_id_in;
  ELSIF v_count < 1
  THEN
     v_count := NULL;
  END IF;

   RETURN v_count;
END UNIQUE_START_STAGE;
```

and then we create an index based the idea that there can only be one child stage that is enabled for a phase that is the start stage

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_start_stage_idx
   ON stage (
      CASE
         WHEN disabled = 1 THEN NULL
         WHEN is_start_stage = 0 THEN NULL
         ELSE UNIQUE_START_STAGE (phase_id, id)
      END);

--and add the same constraint to the other table
```

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_start_stage_idx2
ON PHASE_FIRST_STAGE (
UNIQUE_START_STAGE (phase_id, stage_id));

This solution partially solves the problem:

- it enforces that there is only one entry in STAGE for each value of PHASE_ID where IS_START_STAGE =1 and DISABLED = 0
- it enforces this same uniqueness in PHASE_FIRST_STAGE
- it does not enforce that an entry in STAGE is also in PHASE_FIRST_STAGE
- you could replace the PHASE_FIRST_STAGE table with a view of STAGE that cleans up the last issue